# Ruby on Rails if/unless statment for AJAX destroy when cart is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, cart

I am building webstore. I added a bit of AJAX functionality to add, update and remove items from my cart without refreshing. 
It works perfect as long as there are no items in a cart and render **cart_empty** partial properly.

The problem is when I add few items, and I can update/remove them without refreshing and
finally I remove the last one, and it do not switch to the **cart_empty** partial and there are only empty table headers left from **cart-items** partial.

Can I add some logic to **destroy.js.erb**?

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#cart-item").html("<%= j render 'carts/cart_items' %>");
```

the **show.html.erb** contains this unless function:

```
<% unless current_order.order_items.empty? %>
  <div id="cart-item">
    <%= render 'cart_items' %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div id="cart-empty">
    <%= render 'cart_empty' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Maybe should I modify somehow my controller to check if there are **order_items** in a **current_order**?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `unless` with `else` is regarded as bad form - see [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). You should be testing for the positive `if  current_order.order_items.any?` if there is a else clause.

Comment: ^ Also in the [RuboCop Ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-else-with-unless)

Comment: What (instance) variables are available to you in the `destroy.js.erb`? Do you have access to `@current_order`? Or anything that can be used to check for the presence of cart items for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

A JS.erb template is evaluated in exactly the same way as a HTML template. So you can just add a condition:

```
<% if current_order.order_items.any? %>
  $("#cart-item").html("<%= j render 'carts/cart_items' %>");
<% else %>
  $("#cart-item").html("<%= j render 'carts/cart_empty' %>");
<% end %>
```

None that this implies that current_order is either a helper or a local passes to the view.

But you might want to refactor this and push the condition down to the partial:

```
# carts/cart_items.html.erb
<% if cart_items.none? %>
  <% render :cart_empty %>
<% else %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Which will let you just write:

```
<%= render 'carts/cart_items', cart_items: current_order.order_items %>
```

See:

- [Layouts and Rendering in Rails - passing local variables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)

Comment: I tried to do that this way. But it wasn't working. Probably it was just a typo. Thanks a lot!!!